# TeamCity MSBuild Error - The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, teamcity

```
The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

This is the error I am getting when I try to build ASP.Net projects in TeamCity. The error is pointing to the file, `Reference.cs`.

However, if I just build projects from Visual Studio 2012, then there's no issue with it. I don't quite understand why MSBuild would complain in TeamCity. Perhaps I am not using the correct build configuration? Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need to install WCF Data services on the Build machine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee720179.aspx. Or if it works as a user, then see if the user that Build is running as has the assemblies available.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will install the WCF Data Services components on the build server and see what happens.

Comment: Build Agent not Build Server (though they can sometimes be the same machine)

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?